# How can I create a 'view' of a directory tree in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

In my current dev environment, I have folders with dozens if not hundreds of files, including a plethora of generated files that are copied directly next to source in my working copy. I unfortunately don't have the power to change how any of this works. So to make my life easier, I want to create a 'view' of my source tree. Is this possible? Basically, currently in `/srcroot/`, I have folders `apple/`, `orange/`, and `melon/`. But I don't use the latter 2, so if you `ls` in `/srcroot/`, I want it to just list `apple/`.

One way I *could* accomplish this is by creating a real directory `/srcview/` that has a list of symlinks, one for each of the folders I want. The problem comes with maintenance - if I add a new folder, I don't want to have to manually maintain the symlink view. I could write a script that maintains this, fed from some sort of config file, but I feel like I may be reinventing the wheel.

I'd love to have some sort of file that acts like a directory, but instead returns something like `ls | grep -v "apple" | grep -v "melon" | grep -v "GENERATED"`, obviously with more logic in my actual enlistment.

Lastly, simply creating aliases for the above `ls` won't work, as in practice I use a variety of editors and file browsers that won't know to use my "special ls" command, so it really does have to behave like a normal directory tree.

Thoughts?

Comment: The solution (which is beyond my ability) would seem to be to write a program which uses FUSE - and use it to create a view of the filesystem. https://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/post/creating-a-virtual-filesystem-with-python-and-why-you-need-one/ may be useful in getting you started.

Comment: Another slim possibility, depending on where your limitations are coming in could be for you move /srcroot onto a unionfs type structure and then accessing the underlying filesystem of part of the unionfs that is of interest to you - ie turning the problem on its head.